# A peculiar user name bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts

Any attempt to view the user page of [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16096) results in a blank page. I suspect this is because the name s/he has chosen is identical to the name of a directory in some systems that one (usually, rightly) blocks public access to.

I suppose unless the user chooses another name, his/her user page will never be accessible.

Comment: I am almost tempted to rename my user to /bin and see how that goes.

Comment: Searching "bin" in the user tab of Stack Overflow gives 3 users with that name, and trying to access their user pages has the same result.

Comment: Suprisingly, meta.stackoverflow does not seem to have this reported (for username). Found one tag related one though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74842/minor-bug-broken-bin-tag-on-stackoverflow, whose fix does not apply to the username, as there is some auto-redirection going on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After the next deploy bin will no longer be subjected to the horror of being shunned by the man.  Users named bin everywhere will be able to rejoice.

Comment: But what about people like Bobby Tables? ;)